# MVC: On button click do some database action and stay on same view

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my view currently I have a form and inside those forms I have three other forms, child form is submitted, i want it to forward some method in controller that just performs some database action but then i want to stay on the same page after the database action is performed.

```
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls
@using DatePicker.Models.ViewModels.Appointment
@model DatePicker.Models.ViewModels.Appointment.CreateAppointmentSelectPersons
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    <link href="~/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
}

<h2>Create</h2>
@using(Html.BeginForm("Create","Appointment", FormMethod.Post,new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Step 2</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

       @*ChildForm1*@
        using (Html.BeginForm("AddAttendeeManual", "Attendee"))
        {
             @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.SelectedManualEmail.AppointmentId)
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedManualEmail.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-8 input-group">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SelectedManualEmail.Email, new { id = "Email", @class = "form-control",PlaceHolder="Email"}) <input type='submit' id="btnEmail" class="btn btn-default" value="Add>>" />
                </div>
            </div>
        }


        if (Model.IsSuperOfficeConnected)
        {
           @*ChildFrom2*@
            using (Html.BeginForm("AddAttendeeSuperOffice","Attendee",FormMethod.Post))
            {
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedSuperOfficeEmail.FirstName, new { id = "SelectedSuperOfficeEmail_FirstName" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedSuperOfficeEmail.LastName, new { id = "SelectedSuperOfficeEmail_LastName" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.SelectedSuperOfficeEmail.AppointmentId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedSuperOfficeEmail.SuperOfficePersonId, new { id = "SelectedSuperOfficeEmail_SuperOfficePersonId" })
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedSuperOfficeEmail.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-8 input-group">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SelectedSuperOfficeEmail.Email, new { id = "SelectedSuperOfficeEmail", @class = "form-control", PlaceHolder = "Search in SuperOffice" })

                        <input type='submit' id="btnEmail" class="btn btn-default" value="Add>>" />
                    </div>
                </div>

            }
        }
        if (Model.IsInternalAddressBookEmpty) 
        {
           @*ChildForm3*@
            using (Html.BeginForm("AddAttendeeInternalAddressBook", "Attendee"))
             {
                @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.SelectedAddressBookPerson.FirstName)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.SelectedAddressBookPerson.LastName)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.SelectedAddressBookPerson.AppointmentId)
                 <div class="form-group">
                     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedAddressBookPerson.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                     <div class="col-md-8 input-group">
                         @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SelectedAddressBookPerson.Email, new { id = "SelectedAddressBookPerson", @class = "form-control", PlaceHolder = "Search in AddressBook..." }) <input type='button' id="btnAddressBook" class="btn btn-default" value="Add>>">
                     </div>
                 </div>               
             }

        }


       <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
             <input class="btn btn-default" value="<<Previous"/>
             <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Next>>" />
         </div>
    </div>

}
<style>
    .ui-autocomplete-loading {
        background: url('/Content/themes/base/images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif') no-repeat right center;
    }

</style>
@section Scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js")

    <script type="text/javascript">    
        $(function () {

            $("#SelectedSuperOfficeEmail").
                autocomplete({
                    source: '/Appointment/SuperOfficePerson',
                    minLength: 1,
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        $('#SelectedSuperOfficeEmail').val(ui.item.value);
                        $(@Html.IdFor(m => m.SelectedSuperOfficeEmail.FirstName)).val(ui.item.FirstName);
                        $(@Html.IdFor(m => m.SelectedSuperOfficeEmail.LastName)).val(ui.item.LastName);
                        $(@Html.IdFor(m => m.SelectedSuperOfficeEmail.SuperOfficePersonId)).val(ui.item.ExternalPersonId);
                    }
            });

            $("#SelectedAddressBookPerson").autocomplete({
                source: '/Appointment/AddressBookPerson',
                minLength: 1,
                select: function(event,ui) {
                    $(@Html.IdFor((m=>m.SelectedAddressBookPerson.FirstName))).val(ui.item.FirstName);
                    $(@Html.IdFor(m=>m.SelectedAddressBookPerson.LastName)).val(ui.item.LastName);
                },
            });

        });
    </script>
}
```

this is what i've done in controller

```
[HttpPost]
public void AddAttendeeSuperOffice(CreateAppointmentSelectPersons superOfficePerson)
{
    _attendeeRepository.AddSuperOfficeAttende(superOfficePerson.SelectedSuperOfficeEmail.AppointmentId,
        superOfficePerson.SelectedSuperOfficeEmail.FirstName,
        superOfficePerson.SelectedSuperOfficeEmail.LastName,
        superOfficePerson.SelectedSuperOfficeEmail.Email,
        superOfficePerson.SelectedSuperOfficeEmail.SuperOfficePersonId);

}

[HttpPost]
public void AddAttendeeInternalAddressBook(CreateAppointmentSelectPersons internalAddressbookPerson)
{
    _attendeeRepository.AddInternalAddressBookAttendee(
        internalAddressbookPerson.SelectedAddressBookPerson.AppointmentId,
        internalAddressbookPerson.SelectedAddressBookPerson.FirstName,
        internalAddressbookPerson.SelectedAddressBookPerson.LastName,
        internalAddressbookPerson.SelectedAddressBookPerson.Email);

}

[HttpPost]
public void AddAttendeeManual(CreateAppointmentSelectPersons manualEmail)
{
    _attendeeRepository.AddManualAttendee(manualEmail.SelectedManualEmail.AppointmentId,
        manualEmail.SelectedManualEmail.Email);

}
```

so whenever my childfrom gets submitted, database action takes place but I get forwarded to different link. 
I could use, `return RedirectToAction` but I don't want to load the whole page again, thats makes it kind of slow to load whole thing again.

I thought of using Partial Views but then partial view didn't really help me achieve what I get.

Is there someway to just stay on the same page and make a void call upon child form submission, so that i stay on same page. Maybe, just make the textbox of the child form empty?

Comment: [`@Ajax.BeginForm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: What you could do is return the same view in your httpPost and httpGet. Then the page will get refreshed, but you will be able to add some nice validation. And if your post goes to another action, you can always use the RedirectToAction function

Comment: @Devcon2 i don't want the whole page to be refreshed, that makes it slow at it has to load all the files again.

Comment: @BradChristie can you give an example for my case?

Comment: It sounds like you want to be using Ajax to perform the required DB operations in the background. Personally I do it via jquery, as that is what I am more comfortable with, i've never tried Ajax.BeginForm.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to submit child forms to controller using Ajax.

Assuming the below child form you want to submit,

```
 using (Html.BeginForm("AddAttendeeInternalAddressBook", "Attendee", new{id="frm-child-address"}))
```

then

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(){


  var postData=  $('#frm-child-address').serialize();
  $.post('/Attendee/AddAttendeeInternalAddressBook',{data:postData},function(res){
  //based on server response do whatever you require
  });

});
```

Comment: so if i had to change my Html.BeginForm to Ajax.BeginForm, how would it look?

Comment: @Biplov13, I have not used Ajax.BeginForm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`@Ajax.BeginForm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470349%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) and add a javascript callback that would fire off after the controller's action (database call) has completed.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "done" }))
{
    @* form *@
}

<script type="text/javascript">
  function done(){
    // The database call is complete.
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This is a perfectly valid answer, but I just want to caution against using and recommending `Ajax.BeginForm`. If you know what you're doing and you don't have anything complicated it's a quick way to add a bit of AJAX functionality and move on. However, in situations like this, where the OP doesn't seem to actually know how to use AJAX, it hides functionality, requiring no actual understanding of what's happening, and can be very dangerous as a result.

Comment: @ChrisPratt: This "hides" AJAX like the `@Html.Input` "hides" how to create an input field for a form. All it does is take some of the "mundane" tasks out of the way (like setting up a binding, bundling and sending off form data, etc.). I suppose this does make it less transparent, however it's no different that old ASP where you drag a GridView in and not have to understand tables.

Comment: Yes, but an HTML input isn't contacting servers and manipulating the DOM on the fly. Just look at the number of questions related to some issue with `Ajax.BeginForm` or similar on this site. Invariably, it's always someone who doesn't understand AJAX at all and they're flummoxed because `Ajax.BeginForm` doesn't "just work".

Comment: @ChrisPratt: I could argue the same about GridView, UpdatePanels, ScriptManager, etc. At some point you have to have an expectation that you know what you're working with. jQuery, IMHO, doesn't make the learning curve less steep; if you don't know AJAX, you don't know it regardless of the medium you implement it in.

Comment: And I would actually issue the same caution with those. Helpers are fine when you understand how they work -- basically where you *could* create your own, but you're using the helper as a time saver. They are deplorable when they're used to fill a knowledge gap, generating something because the "developer" doesn't know how to do it themselves.

Comment: @ChrisPratt may sound stupid question, I haven't tried Ajax forms a lot. So the `OnSuccess` option here says when the form is submitted call the done function, but when does it call the controller? and when the controller's method is called won't it try to forward to that method name is browser?

Comment: also another newbie question, when should I use Ajax.BeginForm or to be more precise how would I know that for certain situations Ajax forms are better options

Comment: @Biplov13: It catches and replaces the submit event of the form, so you still need a conventional submit button (`<input type="submit">` or `<button type="submit">`). When the user clicks that, the AJAX request will be issued to the controller action you've specified. As far as when you can use it goes, my only point in the above was that you should take the time to understand what's happening and perhaps build it from scratch *first* just so you can get the hang of it, once you've done that, you can use it whenever you want.

Comment: @Biplov13: Although, I will say that one pretty bad thing about `Ajax.BeginForm` is that it needs a global function to call on complete. It's not a huge deal, especially if you employ good namespacing, but creating your own JavaScript event handler (which doesn't need to be in the globabl namespace) is just cleaner. That's more about personal preference than anything, though.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I converted my forms to Ajax.BeginForms but there were some problems, I tried posting a question via this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21572235/ajaxforms-some-working-some-not can you take a look maybe? Because I don't understand why it is not working